# Fall bei mehreren aufeinanderfolgenden Präpositionen?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Was ist richtig?

> Die Orangen kannst du für unter *einem* Euro pro Kilo kaufen.

oder

> Die Orangen kannst du für unter *einen* Euro pro Kilo kaufen.

Wir haben ja hier zwei Präpositionen vor dem Nomen, und zwar solche die mit verschiedenen Kasus verwendet werden. Ich denke die Präposition, die *direkt* vor dem Nomen steht, sollte den Kasus bestimmen, oder liege ich hier falsch?

Comment: "unter" ist genaugenommen hier keine Präposition, sondern ein Adverb und regiert deshalb keinen Kasus. Die Frage ist gut, das Beispiel paßt aber leider nicht. Ein anderes Beispiel, z.B. "mit oder ohne dich", wäre vielleicht besser.

Comment: @tofro Wie kann man das beurteilen, ob eine Präposition oder ein Adverb? Wenn ich "Du musst  unter einem Euro zahlen" sagte,  ist "unter" dann auch ein Adverb, und ich müsste eigentlich "du musst unter einen Euro zahlen" sagen?

Comment: "unter einem Euro" - hier bezieht sich das "unter" auf den Euro und arbeitet daher nicht als Präposition. Der Online-Duden hat schöne Beispiele dafür.

Comment: "unter" ist ein Adverb, wenn man es durch "weniger als" ersetzen kann und eine Präposition, wenn es eine Position oder eine Richtung angibt (ersteres geht bei "ich stehe unter einer Brücke" nicht, letzteres schon. Bei "Ich zahle unter einen Euro" stimmt ersteres und letzteres nicht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Annahme, es handle sich hier um zwei Präpositionen, ist falsch.

"unter" ist in deinem Beispiel ein *Adverb*.

Das ist immer dann der Fall, wenn man es (wie hier) durch "weniger als" ersetzen kann. Weil es in diesem Fall keine Präposition ist, sondern ein Adverb, regiert es - wie alle Adverbien - keinen Kasus.

"unter" ist nur dann eine *Präposition*, wenn es eine Position oder eine Richtung angibt.

Bei "ich stehe unter einer Brücke" kann man nicht sagen "ich stehe weniger als eine Brücke". Aber sehr wohl bei "ich zahle [unter|weniger als] einen Euro für Kartoffeln".

Dasselbe gilt übrigens für das Pärchen "mehr als"/"über" genauso.